# How to use WPF Prism correctly in a project without Application class or without overriding it?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, visual-studio-extensions

Can Prism be used without overriding the Application class? For example, when developing an extension for Visual Studio. I have not found examples of how this can be done.

Comment: You can go with a non-`Window` shell or no shall at all, but there's no support (i.e. updates may break things unexpectedly): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333568/prism-7-using-prismapplication-createshell-with-a-non-window-control/54343953#54343953

Comment: @SnowyOwl, does Haukinger's answer help you handle the issue?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT yes, I chose another framework for my task.

Comment: @SnowyOwl, since Haukinger's answer does help to your issue, I have added his tip into an answer and you can consider accepting it to help other community members search and handle similar issues. And if you have an improvement , you could also add your workaround as answer to help improve the ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333568/prism-7-using-prismapplication-createshell-with-a-non-window-control/54343953#54343953). You can use the related code and you can still use them:

```
protected override Window CreateShell()
{
    return null;
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var shellWindow = Container.Resolve<ShellWindow>();
    shellWindow.Show();
    MainWindow = shellWindow.ParentOfType<Window>();

    // there lines was not executed because of null Shell - so must duplicate here. Originally called from PrismApplicationBase.Initialize
    RegionManager.SetRegionManager(MainWindow, Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>());
    RegionManager.UpdateRegions();
    InitializeModules();

    base.OnInitialized();
}
```